# Subscribe to something like on object instance being assigned event

Tags: c#

Here is what I am trying to do. I am making a class which contains indexer for accessing fields within the class, and for adding/removing new fields. Basically the class is like a class with set of static and dynamic fields. I am using a dictionary for the indexer. My problem is that how would I find out and update the static object in the dictionary when the user explicitly reinitialized one of the field? example:

```
public class foo
{
}

public class bar
{
    Dictionary<string, foo> dict = new Dictionary<string, foo>();

    public bar()
    {
         //using reflection to initialize all fields
    }

    public foo this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            return dict[name];
        }
    }
}

public class bar2:bar //Note: defined by the user, can't use get/setter to update it
{
      public foo field1; 
      public foo field2;
      public foo field3;
}

public static void main()
{
    bar2 test = new bar2();
    test.field1 = new foo();
    test["field1"] //this points to the old field1. How can I update it automatically when test.field1 = new foo(); is called?
}
```

Some of you might suggest me to use reflection to do it, but what if the user called remove "field1" and added a new dynamic field called field1, I would want to return the new one created by the user instead of the one defined in the class.

Comment: take a look at this site it's very easy to understand the examples have you researched how to create and or use Indexers and when to use them..? http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Class-Interface/IndexingwithMultipleParameters.htm also read up on the difference between `Static Class vs Instance`

Comment: Please elaborate. You have a statically-declared field "field1" in your class. How is a user going to _remove_ that field? Also, your code in main() shows use of an indexer, but you didn't declare one in the bar class. If you want good answers, you need to post real code, and ensure the example is concise and complete.

Comment: @PeterDuniho the remove is mostly used for removing dynamic fields created by user. But I can never control what the user is going to do. So I have to assume that they might try to remove the static field and create a new dynamic one with the same name. In that case indexer should return the dynamic one. Can't post the real code sry..

Comment: @DJKRAZE well ikr how to create indexer, just forgot to include them.. sorry. And by static fields I mean predefined fields not "static [type] field"

Answer (score 1):

If your users and defining fields then you will need to adjust your logic to dynamically look up the result every time. Luckily you can avoid most of the reflection overhead by storing the field in your dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, FieldInfo> dict = new Dictionary<string, FieldInfo>();

public bar()
{
    //If you are using reflection you should be getting this
    FieldInfo info;
    dict[info.Name] = info;
}

public foo this[string name]
{
    get { return dict[name].GetValue(this); }
    set { dict[name].SetValue(this, value); }
}
```

Comment: sry for the confusion, question updated. And I can't use get/set since it is a field defined by the user